# Rotating a cube with keyboard key in three.js

Tags: three.js

How to rotate around a cube object with a keyboard key?

[image: three.js cube]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/ne7gjdnq/87/) is an example of using the arrow keys to rotate a cube.
The main parts you want to take note of are..

Adding the key event listener:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressed);
```

responding to the keyboard event:

```
function keyPressed(e){
  switch(e.key) {
    case 'ArrowUp':
        mesh.rotateX(-0.1);
        break;
    case 'ArrowDown':
        mesh.rotateX(0.1);
        break;
    case 'ArrowLeft':
        mesh.rotateY(-0.1);
        break;
    case 'ArrowRight':
        mesh.rotateY(0.1);
        break;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  render();
}
```

This example rotates the cube, if you wanted to rotate the camera around the cube the code in the event listener would be different, but how the listener is attached would remain the same.

Comment: it's works !! thanks a lot  :)

Comment: ok, sorry :(  i'm beginner here